# Moveit! Wiki gone without trace

Tags: ros, moveit, wiki

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The MoveIt! wiki seems to have disappeared without a trace -  Google is still returning results for it at the top of its listings.

Unfortunately much of the documentation has not been replaced in any other location.

For an example, here is a link to a search: [Google search for "ROS Planning Scene"](https://www.google.com/search?q=ROS+planning+scene&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8).

In my mind this is a really serious problem - what is the successor for the old MoveIt! wiki at http://moveit.ros.org/wiki/? There doesn't seem to be a clear one.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/217870/moveit!-wiki-gone-without-trace/) by [bjem85](https://answers.ros.org/users/18596/bjem85/) on ROS Answers with karma: 163 on 2015-09-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A redirect has been added to http://moveit.ros.org/wiki. If there are other links that need to be redirected, please send an email on moveit-users.

Thanks!

---

Originally posted by [MoveIt Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/23956/moveit-robot/) with karma: 16 on 2015-09-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bjem85](https://answers.ros.org/users/18596/bjem85/) on 2015-09-19**:
The problem with the new site (which I had found before posting the question) is that it lacks several features from the old wiki, most notably a search function. This is what I meant by "no clear successor".

**Comment by [MoveIt Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/23956/moveit-robot/) on 2015-09-19**:
Would you like to elaborate on what other features apart from a search function you are looking for. Also the website is based on github pages so it's easy for the community to add features using a pull request :-)